# Updating database with certain date

Tags: php, mysql

For my internship i'm almost done with a program though i need to make it so i can update my database. The problem here is that i can not update it using the date selected by the user due to the timestamp in the database. is there any way i can either add a time behind my variable or make it so i can have my update query ignore the time part?

Here is the current code for my program's update query.

```
if(isset($_POST['Pasaan'])) 
                    {
                        $Voor = $_POST['Voor0900'];
                        $Na = $_POST['Na0900'];
                        $Datum = $_POST['Datum'];
                        $Datum = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y" , $Datum);
                        $Datum->format('Y-m-d');
                        $Datum
                        $sql = "UPDATE `firsthousing` SET 
                        `Voor0900` = '$Voor', 
                        `Na0900` = '$Na' 
                        WHERE Datum = '$Datum'";
                        if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) 
                        {
                            echo "New record created successfully";
                        } else 
                        {
                            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $db->error;
                        }
                    }
```

With kind regards,
Daynie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `DATE()` which will only return date part

```
$sql = "UPDATE `firsthousing` SET 
                        `Voor0900` = '$Voor', 
                        `Na0900` = '$Na' 
                        WHERE DATE(Datum) = '$Datum'";
```

Comment: Hmm... i tried though it does not want to update the database. Oh.. and the Datum part is the date name in the table.

Comment: @Daynie You haven't really assigned a variable to the correctly formatted date. You do `$Datum->format('Y-m-d');` but the result doesn't go anywhere. So something like `$DatumStr = $Datum->format('Y-m-d')` and use `$DatumStr` in the query

Comment: Thanks for all the help. i figured out a way to change the datetime in my database to just date.. stupid me sometimes. xD anyway thanks for the help. i'm sure i'll figure it out now.